# Rails scope json field on joins relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models

**Form.rb**

```
has_many :elements
```

**Element**

```
belongs_to :form
```

I want to query Elements like this:

```
Element.joins(:form).where(hash)
hash = {
  form: {
    name: "some name", 
    surname: "some surname"
  }, 
  element_name: "some name" 
}
```

these attributes are both from Form and Element models, and this works fine. Now i need to scope Forms with 1 more attribute (*date*) which is stored in meta attribute (json field) so Form object looks like:

```
Form
  - name
  - surname
  - meta: {date: "2018-10-10"}
```

I have created scope that can work like this:

```
scope :by_date, ->(date) { where('JSON_EXTRACT(meta, "$.date") = ?', date) }
Form.by_date("2018-10-10")
```

and this works fine, but how can i use this scope in above scenario since i can't do:

```
hash = {
      form: {
        name: "some name", 
        surname: "some surname",
        date: "2018-10-10"
      }, 
      element_name: "some name" 
    }
```

Comment: does `Element.joins(:form).where(hash).form.by_date(date)` work?

Comment: @Anthony im getting undefined method form for Element::ActiveRecord_Relation, i believe there must some more elegant way

Comment: `Element.joins(:form).where(hash).where(form_id: Form.by_date(date).select(:id))` will take care of it for you by using a subquery to handle the json part

Comment: @engineersmnky sorry for such a late reply, this worked!